# [Laravel]: How do I dependency inject into an abstract class extended by other classes(jobs)

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, abstract, solid-principles

I have a Laravel project where I have created an abstract class that several of my jobs will use as they all need to use the same method to find some data to proceed.

In Laravel, the way jobs work is that the constructor takes any values that you trigger the job with and in a handler method, dependencies can be injected, like so:

```
class SomeJob extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function __construct(array $someData, int $someMoreData)
    {
        $this->someData     = $someData;
        $this->someMoreData = $someMoreData;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // Do something...
    }
}


\Queue::pushOn(Queue::getDefaultQueue(), new SomeJob([1, 2, 3], 4));
```

This means that I cannot just pass dependencies into the abstract class from the extending class' constructor. The only way around it, that I can see, is to have a property on the abstract class and then set it in the handler method of the extended class.

```
abstract class SomeAbstractClass extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $configOne;
    protected $configTwo;
    protected $userRepository;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->configOne = config('someConfig.valueOne');
        $this->configTwo = config('someConfig.valueTwo');
    }

    public function doSomethingWithUserRepository()
    {
        return $this->userRepository->doSomething();
    }
}

class SomeClass extends SomeAbstractClass
{
    public function __construct(array $someData, int $someMoreData)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->someData     = $someData;
        $this->someMoreData = $someMoreData;
    }

    public function handle(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }
}
```

This works as intended, but it does not seem like the correct way to do it. It seems a bit hacky even if it works. Is there a way to get around this? This must he a pretty common problem, also outside of Laravel.

Comment: If your queue was setup to use Laravel's [queue jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues), you could probably pass both dependencies and arguments through the constructor (as per the docs on [automatic injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#automatic-injection)), but I haven't tried this sorry. Alternatively, are you familiar with the [`resolve()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-resolve) helper method? You could call this from you abstract constructor to setup your dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did not know about the resolve method, but as I am on 5.2 I cannot use it. But perhaps I can do something similar to what it does. I will look into it. Thank you. Issue is still open for a qualified answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the defined constructor is used to deliver data in the jobs in Laravel, so in this case, you have to treat `handle()` as the "constructor" method.

So consider this example:

```
<?php
abstract class SomeAbstractClass extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $configOne;
    protected $configTwo;
    protected $userRepository;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->configOne = config('someConfig.valueOne');
        $this->configTwo = config('someConfig.valueTwo');
    }

    public function handle(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    protected function doSomethingWithUserRepository()
    {
        return $this->userRepository->doSomething();
    }
}

class SomeClass extends SomeAbstractClass
{
    public function __construct(array $someData, int $someMoreData)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->someData     = $someData;
        $this->someMoreData = $someMoreData;
    }

    public function handle(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        parent::handle($userRepository);

        // you can do whatever you liiike
        $this->doSomethingWithUserRepository();
    }
}
```